# mkdir -pv not verbose

Tags: macos, bash, mkdir

If I run `mkdir -pv`, the `-p` works, but I do not get verbose output; however, if I run just `mkdir -v`, the verbose output appears as expected. Also potentially of note, the longform of `-v` does not seem to work at all.

From my testing:
`mkdir -p a/b/c`: creates `a/`, `a/b/`, and `a/b/c/`, gives no output to terminal (as expected)

`mkdir -v d`: creates `d/` and outputs `mkdir: created directory 'd'` (as expected)

`mkdir -pv e/f/g`: creates `e/`, `e/f/`, and `e/f/g/`, gives no output to terminal (why?)

`mkdir --verbose h`: gives a `illegal option -- -` error (why?)

---

**Update**: I filed a bug report with Apple for this issue, and received the following reply:

[image]

Their answer that "-v is not applicable" does not make much sense to me, since `mkdir -v` works just fine, but since there are various workarounds and I am no longer even using OSX, I don't think it's worth pursuing any further to me.

Comment: Does `mkdir --help` report `--verbose` for you? That might be a GNU-ism.

Comment: Did you ever file a bug report on this?

Comment: @jsejcksn Yes, I did eventually go back and file a bug report and was told this is working as intended (full reply has been added to my question).

Comment: That's unfortunate. Thanks for filling the report.

Comment: I just ran into this as well. I did `mkdir -pv folder1/folder2/folder3` and it created all directories but there was no console output.  However I get console output with `mkdir -v foldername`. Such a shame.

Comment: Wow! This is very broken, and calling it as-designed is such a boneheaded answer. It means the method is poorly written and doesn't pass through command flags or perhaps doesn't reuse code for the simple case. This should be reported to the FreeBSD and/or Darwin teams since Apple does nothing (when they should be reporting it).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Macs use BSD-based code that is (mostly) POSIX compliant but (mostly) without GNU extensions (such as double-dash long options).  The man page does document `-v` and `-p`, and `-p` works but does seem to suppress the `-v` option (which is probably when it is most useful).

One of your options is to file a bug with the Darwin or BSD teams, or with Apple.  That's the way it is; it is arguably not the way it should be.  (GNU `mkdir` supports `-v` and prints the directories it creates when used with `-p`, which makes more sense, and supports the 'it is a bug' contention.)

*With thanks to [SnoringFrog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/919057/snoringfrog):*

Another option is to install and use the GNU `mkdir` command on OSX.  It is part of GNU coreutils and you could install it as explained in [How to replace Mac OS X utilities with GNU core utilities](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69223/how-to-replace-mac-os-x-utilities-with-gnu-core-utilities) at [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com). Then, you could alias `mkdir` to point to `gmkdir` to get the expected behavior (assuming you don't use `--default-names` when installing the GNU tools).

Comment: Ah, yeah, forgot about that. Since I've got Gnu tools installed, I'll just have to alias mkdir to gmkdir. I'll edit a bit about that into your answer, since it'll help anyone who lands on this get the behavior they expect, at least.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this if logging is critical (since the `-v` flag works in the simple case):

```
mkdir -v path && 
mkdir -v path/to && 
mkdir -v path/to/{destination1,destination2,etc} ;
```

**Think Different** or **Think Again**?!